# SVN access in Perl

Tags: perl, svn

I want to write a perl script by which I can checkout/checkin files from SVN repository.
I checked some Perl modules like `Alien::SVN`, `SVN::Core`, `SVN::Client` etc.

But I could not really find any function which does file checkout or check-in.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SVN::Client](https://metacpan.org/module/SVN%3a%3aClient) can both checkout and checkin files.

Here's an excerpt from the docs on how to checkout:

> ```
>     $ctx->checkout($url, $path, $revision, $recursive, $pool);
> ```
>
> Checkout a working copy of $url at $revision using $path as the root directory of the newly checked out working copy.
>
> `$revision` must be a number, 'HEAD', or a date. If $revision does not meet these requirements the `$SVN::Error::CLIENT_BAD_REVISION` is
>   raised.
>
> Returns the value of the revision actually checked out of the repository.

And for checkin:

> ```
> $ctx->commit($targets, $nonrecursive, $pool);
> ```
>
> Commit files or directories referenced by target. Will use the log_msg callback to obtain the log message for the commit.
>
> If $targets contains no paths (zero elements), then does nothing and immediately returns without error.
>
> Calls the notify callback as the commit progresses with any of the following actions:
>
> ```
> $SVN::Wc::Notify::Action::commit_modified,
> $SVN::Wc::Notify::Action::commit_added,
> $SVN::Wc::Notify::Action::commit_deleted,
> $SVN::Wc::Notify::Action::commit_replaced,
> $SVN::Wc::Notify::Action::commit_postfix_txdelta.
> ```
>
> Use `$nonrecursive` to indicate that subdirectories of directory targets should be ignored.
>
> Returns a svn_client_commit_info_t object. If the revision member of the commit information object is `$SVN::Core::INVALID_REVNUM` and no
>   error was raised, then the commit was a no-op; nothing needed to be
>   committed.

Comment: I tried this code and I am getting this error while accessing the repo. `Bad URL passed to RA layer: Unrecognized URL scheme for <repo url>`

Comment: I fixed it. I had to install `neon` library.

Comment: Sure, I will accept your answer. I am facing some more problems. `RA layer request failed: Unable to connect to a repository at URL <url> The OPTIONS request returned invalid XML in the response: XML parse error at line 1: Extra content at the end of the document`

Comment: @cppcoder I've actually never used this module myself. I'd open a new question and add as much detail as possible, i.e. a dump of the data that seems to be invalid. I bet there are a lot more people able to help. They just can't find this issue because it's hidden in a comment of an old question.