# SVN checkout via perl script

Tags: perl, svn

i want to do SVN checkout by using perl script.
basically want to automate SVN checkout process.

Comment: And Where is your code? what have you tried?

Comment: i m a begineer in PERL script, so want to know the process of automation by using system commands in perl, it ll be appriciated if u can guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [SVN::Client](https://metacpan.org/module/SVN::Client) for this purpose. Also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13272000/257635).

Comment: thnx buddy i ll refer this section

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should search well before posting a question. Check out the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: hey i got below script from SVN::Client. here what url i have to pass ?                                                          $ctx->checkout($url, $path, $revision, $recursive, $pool);

Comment: This is a URL to a subversion repository. BTW I would suggest you to learn Perl first. SVN::Client is a module which you can use in your Perl program. You'll have to install it via CPAN. Go to http://learn.perl.org and learn basic Perl.